# Is there a method to concatenate different activity TextView in EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

There are 3 activities. The text value of Textview in the first and second activity is shown in EditText of third activity.

Mainactivity - Textview1 text

Secondactivity - Textview2 text

Displayactivity - Edittext=Textview1+Textview2

Using intent I have tried to pass the the TextView values of both activities to third activity. In the third activity I concatenated by simply using + in EditText. I am trying to show previous textview values in one paragraph i.e. EditText.

This code is on third activity :

**Display activity**

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();

 String displayingtext = intent.getStringExtra("message");

 String displayingsecondtext = intent.getStringExtra("hey");

 editText.setText(displayingtext+displayingsecondtext);
```

displayingtext name: message is from first activity

displaysecondtext name : hey is from second activity

The output displayed is from the first textview and the next word null.

In the code it shows

> "Don't use concatenate on setText. Use android resources"

***Input***:

Textview1= Hello,monday.

Textview2=Bye, monday.

***Expected Output:***

Editext=Hello,monday.Bye monday.

Comment: are you sending data you got from activity one to activity 3 from activity 2

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it.. It is saying that you have to put them in resources.. 
If your application doesn't use multiple language support,  then you can simply neglect the warning

Comment: There won't be modification to text values.

Comment: After putting to shared preferences you can access them in anywhere in your application. You can access them from any activity

Answer (score 0):

Use **concat()** method from java.lang.String insted of "+" operator.

```
String displayingtext = intent.getStringExtra("message");

 String displayingsecondtext = intent.getStringExtra("hey");

 editText.setText(displayingtext.concat(displayingsecondtext));
```

Comment: I will be adding couple of textview values to it. So, concatenation for around 10 textview values is possible through concat()?

Answer (score 0):

U need to send the "message" got form Activity1 & "hey" in the Activity2 startActivity intent param to Activity3.

It is just a warning as Android Studio Lint tool check the setText method param use a '+' operator. Consider fix it like this:

```
String resultText = displayingtext+displayingsecondtext;
editText.setText(resultText);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This gave me idea to something else and it worked :D I upvoted but my vote is not casted because I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

Using greenbot event bus you can do it better...

[best example for event bus try it...](https://tutorialwing.com/android-eventbus-library-example/)